# Is it possible / common sense to change a CIDR prefix to meet a certain requirement of a network?

Tags: ipv4, subnet

Say for example, you have an IP address with a CIDR prefix of /27 (mask of 255.255.255.224) and are required to create 4 subnets each with an equal amount of usable host addresses, would it be commonplace / accepted to adjust the prefix to /26 (using only 2 additional
bits, leaving 6 for the Host ID) to allow for 4 subnets, each with 62 (60 usable addresses ?

Or

Is just a case of when a prefix is already set (in this case /27) you simply “get what your given” and utilise only 4 of the possible 8 subnets that can be created with the additional 3 bits and have 4 subnets, each with 32 (30 usable addresses)?

I understand the prefix denotes how many bits are considered significant for the network address with the remainder allocated for the host / node.

Thanks in advance, I am quite new to networking but feel like common sense might apply in this case?

I haven to been able to find anything that confirms or denies the possibility of doing this when required.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and thus is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I noticed I tagged network-programming  accidentally.

Comment: Nice question (I'm gonna forward to the cisco instructors at work, it would make a good discussion for our students) but unfortunately OT for SO.  Try the network engineering SE - https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ Giving you a +1 but flagging to have it moved....